# Internal server error 500 when sending ajax post request in laravel 9

Tags: ajax, laravel, post, server, internals

I am using laravel 9. I am trying to make a ajax crud operation using alax. It respond well in get request. but when I sending  the post request it shows:

http://127.0.0.1:8000/add/teacher 500 (Internal Server Error) in the console. I used meta in the head and ajax csrf header according to documentation. Still showing error. here my ajax code example bellow:

```
<script>
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });

    $(document).ready(function() {


        $(".add_teacher").on('click', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var name = $("#name").val();
            var email = $("#email").val();
            var position = $("#position").val();
            var phone = $("#phone").val();
            var password = $("#password").val();

            $.ajax({
                method: "post",
                url: "{{route('store')}}",
                data: {
                    name: name,
                    email: email,
                    position: position,
                    phone: phone,
                    password: password
                },
                success: function(res) {
                    if (res.status == 'success') {
                        $("#exampleModal").modal('hide');
                        $("#modalform")[0].reset();
                        $(".table").load(location.href + ' .table');
                    }
                },
                error: function(err) {
                    let error = err.responseJSON;
                    $.each(error.errors, function(index, value) {
                    $(".errorMessage").append('<span class="text- 
                      danger">' + value +'</span><br>');
                    });
                }
            });

        });


    });
</script>
```

Here is my route:

```
Route::post('/add/teacher', [TeacherController::class,'store'])->name('store');
```

and my controller code is:

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {

        $request->validate(
            [
                "name"      => "required",
                "email"     => "requied|unique:teachers",
                "position"  => "requied",
                "phone"     => "requied|unique:tachers",
                "password"  => "requied",
            ],
            [
                "name.required" => "Name is required",
                "email.required" => "Email is required",
                "email.unique" => "Email already exists",
                "position.required" => "Postion is required",
                "phone.required" => "Phone is required",
                "phone.unique" => "Phone already exixts",
                "password.required" => "password is required",
            ]
        );

        $teacher = new Teacher();
        $teacher->name = $request->name;
        $teacher->email = $request->email;
        $teacher->position = $request->position;
        $teacher->phone = $request->phone;
        $teacher->password = $request->password;
        $teacher->save();
        return response()->json([
            'status' => 'success',
        ]);
    }
```

[image: here is the screenshot in network tab]
Now I need an exact solution to go farther. Thank you.

Comment: If you don't show what the error is, we cannot help, as a 500 could mean literally anything. Go to the Networks tab, click on the failed request and read the `response` to see if you have anything back as an error, also check the laravel log...

Comment: @MDMAHIUDDIN I have told you what to do, ignore the console but go to the networks tab...

Comment: Ok, I attached the image of my network panel. Actually I can't Identify where is the problem. Sometime it showing get method is not supported, supported method is post. But I already used post method.

Comment: In the network panel you see the red error. Click on it. Click on the response tab. Show the results. Also: you'll have an error in your `storage/logs/laravel.log` copy/paste that error *with its stacktrace*

Comment: Thanks bro. I have already solved this problem. It was a tiny problem. just missing on the the validation. I found it using the console log. Thank you so much.